# Cloud Build for Google App Engine - Flexible is failing with a generic 'exit status 1'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, socket.io, app-engine-flexible, google-cloud-build

I'm testing how to build a pipeline on GCP and after successfully deploying an Angular 6 application I wanted to add a websocket (socket.io) backend that will serve real time updates.

First of all the error itself, which is results of this command:

`gcloud builds submit --verbosity=debug --config stage.cloudbuild.yaml .`

```
[...]
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DEBUG: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 29412e5a-cd7f-4af8-9b83-71fb17414dc2 completed with status "FAILURE"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[UsernameRedacted]\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\[UsernameRedacted]\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\[UsernameRedacted]\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\builds\submit.py", line 497, in Run
    raise FailedBuildException(build)
FailedBuildException: build 29412e5a-cd7f-4af8-9b83-71fb17414dc2 completed with status "FAILURE"
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 29412e5a-cd7f-4af8-9b83-71fb17414dc2 completed with status "FAILURE"
[...]
[ ... NPM saying it's not its fault yada yada ... ]
```

My local environment is:
Node: 10.9.0
NPM: 6.2.0
OS: Windows 10

The following is the app.yaml file (specifically stage.app.yaml):

```
service: mercury
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

instance_class: B1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

env_variables:
  MERCURY_PORT: 5001
  MERCURY_SECRET: [REDACTED]

network:
  session_affinity: true
```

And the cloudbuild.yaml (specifically stage.cloudbuild.yaml):

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'install' ]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: [ 'app', 'deploy', 'stage.app.yaml', '-v=stage' ]
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mercury",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "socket.io event manager",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "deploy-stage": "gcloud builds submit --config stage.cloudbuild.yaml .",
    "deploy-prod": "gcloud builds submit --config prod.cloudbuild.yaml ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.18.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.0",
    "log-timestamp": "^0.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.9.0"
  }
}
```

[Link to gist with the configurations used for the angular app](https://gist.github.com/theCrius/c91eefb354ca40ce6ed351c8d35efa4d) as requested by @SamuelN. It's an ionic app so it's a little different from the regular "Heroes" app.

Seems like something is wrong in some python script in my local machine but honestly I don't know how I should fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you deploy the Angular 6 app the first thime? Was it through a Cloud Build script? Can you post the full content of your cloudbuild.yaml configuration file here to enable me to reproduce and troubleshoot your method. Be sure to redact any sensitive information first.

Comment: Also you concluded by saying "seems like something is wrong in some *python script* in your local machine", what python script are you referring to? Is there an error log that you can provide? If that were the case then it would be very useful. Finally, what happens when you remove the breaking change in your source code and redeploy your app? If you were able to successfully automate the deployment of your app using Cloud Build earlier then maybe this could be a clue to something wrong in your code? I'd be happy to help as best as I can.

Comment: Hey @SamuelN, thanks for commenting, in the stack trace of the error response you can already see that it references `googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py`, `googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py` and `googlecloudsdk\calliope\submit.py`.

I'm gonna edit the question to include the yaml for the angular application as well.

Comment: I just tested the same application from another computer using a clean Ubuntu v18 and I get the exact same error message: imgur.com/a/ApEZAZx. Just ruling out that it is an OS or machine issue.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend you open a support case on google cloud support as I think this would be easier to check the issue by them [1]. 
  
[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/